# Laravel Dusk - click on element based on attribute

Tags: php, laravel, webdriver, laravel-dusk

I have this code:

```
   <ul class="changed each time" data-auto="timeSlots" aria-label="Choose party time">
   <li datetime="2019-06-03T14:30" offset="-30" type="standard">
      <button offset="-30" role="link">2:30 pm</button>
   </li>
   <li  datetime="2019-06-03T14:45" offset="-15" type="standard">
      <button  offset="-15" role="link">2:45 pm</button>
   </li>
   <li  datetime="2019-06-03T15:00" offset="0" type="standard">
      <button  offset="0" role="link">3:00 pm</button>
   </li>
   <li  datetime="2019-06-03T17:30" offset="150" type="standard">
      <button  offset="150" role="link">5:30 pm</button>
   </li>
   <li >
   <button  disabled="" role="link"></button></li>
</ul>
```

I'm using Laravel Dusk and 
How I can click on a button based on datetime attribute?

I tried:

```
$browser->click($browser->element('li[datetime="2019-06-03T15:00"]'))->pause(2000);
```

but I got an error:

> ErrorException (E_WARNING) preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be
>   string, object given

Is there any way to click on an attribute?

Comment: Just pass a string, don't pass the element. `$browser->click('li[datetime="2019-06-03T15:00"]')`. The click function expects a selector (as a string) and not a `browser` element, hence the preg_match error.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy This dont works

Comment: Try these 2 links too which are extremely useful for me [github](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/303#issuecomment-311656596) and [forum](https://www.5balloons.info/understanding-selectors-laravel-dusk-browser-testing)

Answer (score 0):

this worked:

$btn = $browser->element('YOUR_SELECTOR');

$btn->click();